# MS Access 2010 - Conditional Insert/Update Statement

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, conditional-statements, ms-access-2010

I have 2 queries in MS Access. One inserts a new user into a database table, the other updates user's record if the key exists in the database.

Is there a way that I can merge the two queries, to insert the record if it doesn't exist, but update it if it does?

Something like

```
-- IF username doesn't exist in the database --
INSERT INTO table_user ( username, gender ) VALUES ( @username, @gender )
-- ELSE --
UPDATE table_user SET gender = @gender WHERE username = @username
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use the following solution:

```
UPDATE Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.[KeyField] = Table2.[KeyField]
SET Table1.[KeyField] = Table2.[KeyField],
Table1.[OtherField] = Table2.[OtherField]
```

If it is in `Table2`, it will be inserted into `Table1`, overwriting the value (updating), if it's already in `Table1`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not comparing 2 tables, I'm inserting data from my application